# How does the "r+" mode to fopen work

Tags: c, file

I am trying to write a program which reads a file and doubles every apparition of a character which is read from standard input.

```
fisier1 = fopen("data.txt", "r+");
char c;
do
{
    c = fgetc(fisier1);
    //fflush(fisier1);
    if(c == x)
    {
        fprintf(fisier1, "%c", x);
        fseek(fisier1, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        printf("$\n");
    }
}
while(c != EOF);
fclose(fisier1);
```

The `printf("$\n");` checks if the character which has to be doubled is reached as many times as its appearances in file, and it's correct. But the content of file remains the same after running the program.
I understand the difference between `r+` and `w+`;  what I don't understand is why this program won't double every 'x' character read from input.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first problem here is that you cannot read and then *immediately* write to the same file. You need an intermediate instruction, such as an `fseek`. Another problem is that if you get it to work, it will double up those characters ... by overwriting the next one! Files do not support "inserting". You are better off finding another solution.

Comment: Now i understand..so there is no way that the number of characters per total would be bigger than the initial number. Am i getting this right, @RadLexus?

Comment: Yes; the file will only grow if you add characters at the end. The best way is to create a new file (and you'll see it's much easier as well).

Comment: Note:   `while(c != EOF);` is infinite look when `char` is unsigned. use `int c;`.